# Mongodb gets locked when working with crontab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cron

I'm creating an application that pulls data from APIs and save it to a MongoDB using `crontab`.

This is an example of what my `crontab` file look like:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/`whoami`/TLC/dataProvider1.js
*/1 * * * * /home/`whoami`/TLC/dataProvider2.js
*/3 * * * * /home/`whoami`/TLC/dataProvider3.js
```

The scripts are JS files that I've made executable and they all have a `require` statement for a separate file that has a database connection, so each of them connects to the DB so it can save the pulled data.
DB connection file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var connect = function () {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/vario', {
        socketTimeoutMS: 0,
        keepAlive: true,
        reconnectTries: 30,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        autoReconnect: true,
        keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000
    });
};
connect();

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Connection established to the Database...');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Could not connect to Database.\nError: ' + err);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
        console.log('Force to close the MongoDB conection');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

module.exports = connect;
```

**Problem:** When these jobs run for about an hour, MongoDB somehow gets locked and no more data can be saved. Firing the mongo shell produces an error that the connection has been refused. Using `mongod` to recover also gives an error that another instance on the data file (/data/db/) is already running so it cannot lock the `mongod.lock` file. The only way I'm dealing with this right now is by shutting down the deamon and restarting it. How can I handle this?

**Note:** I used `crontab` because `setInterval` was interfering with browsing the app in case it was saving to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a careful inspection, I realized that my `crontab` jobs were creating new connections to the DB that were never closed. All I had to do is ensure that a connection is closed when a script finishes running.